# Tomcat/JAAS - Looking up DataSource

Tags: tomcat, datasource, jndi, jaas

We have a newly written JAAS module and were wondering where to place the database connection setting for the DataSource object.

Typically in a Tomcat web application, this would be reference in the 'web.xml' file to point to an XML file located in '$catalina_home/conf/Catalina/localhost'.

Where can we place similar configuration for a JAAS module (deployed in a Tomcat)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay - the above works - no problem.

It fails only when a context is used for the webapp; more troubleshooting ahead :)